# Keep background color on highlighted cells

Tags: handsontable

Handsontable overrides a cell's background color when the highlighting plugin is activated, as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z71U.gif) shows.

Is there a way to keep the background color when highlighting?

[Example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI7xJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's a little hard to see what you're doing, but essentially, you will have to use the `!important` tag on your css rule. For example, if you had a rule on your td's that turned the background pink, you'd do the following:

```
td.pinkCell {
    background-color:pink!important;
}
```

This will ensure the highlighting does not override your property.

Answer (score 0):

```
.handsontable .currentRow { 
    background-color: rgba(225, 250, 255, 1);
} 
.handsontable .currentCol { 
    background-color: rgba(225, 250, 255, 1);
}
```

The purpose was able to be accomplished in this. Thank you for an answer.